# How to Searching String from PDF using iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, pdf, ios4, core-graphics

I am trying to create a PDF Reader application allow user to search string from the PDF. The very simple idea for displaying the PDF in webView but I don't know whether I can perform search in the PDF displayed in UIWebView or not?

If this is possible then please provide me any good tutorial for this. If not then I am using CGPDFDocumentRef and other classes of CoreGraphics. I am done with displaying PDF on a UIView without having UIWebView. I am unable to Zoom yet but it is displaying. Now for searching I have used this tutorial. http://www.random-ideas.net/posts/42. I am able to search and getting a bool value for string is available or not. but I am not getting how to highlight search text in PDF.

Please help me if it is possible with any one, UIWebView or the way I am doing using CoreGraphics.

Thanks.