# Highlighting Text in pdf using iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone, pdf, quartz-2d

I had asked a question earlier [How to Searching String from PDF using iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339065/how-to-searching-string-from-pdf-using-iphone-sdk)

I got a answer but that wasn't I was looking for. I am not sure to ask something similar as new question or not.

I am using ios4.2.
I am working on a application which display PDF. I am using Quartz 2D for that. I have gone through apple documentation and googleing of around 4 days I didn't find any thing that suits to me in this case. There are lots of question related to this and almost all answers are redirecting to either
[Random Ideas](http://www.random-ideas.net/posts/42) or
[FastKit](https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit).

Random Ideas don't explain how to highlight a text within the pdf. and FastKit has implementation but no Explaination too. I don't want to use fastkit because It shows its logo. can any one please give me any link which has some libraries or apis or any thing for highlighting text in PDF while I am using Quartz 2D.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks In Advance.